# What is different between *.bat and *.sh and *.exe file?

Tags: batch-file, tomcat, command-line, sh

When I start Apache Tomcat

```
start
    tomcat/bin/startup.bat
    tomcat/bin/startup.sh
stop
    tomcat/bin/shutdown.bat
    tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
```

**1. What is different between *.sh and *.bat and *.exe file?**

So I know file follow that is like a program.

```
 - *bat, *cmd - Batch, Comand
 - *exe - C
 - *jar - Java
```

I can read, understand script content in the *bat file.

**2. Why don't use *exe instead *sh, *bat file to run ?**

**3. How the structure is in *bat, *sh, *exe file ?**

Answer (score 26):

A `.bat` file is a windows batch file it contains a sequence of windows/dos commands. These cannot be used in a Unix shell prompt.

A `.sh` file is a unix shell script it contains a series of unix commands. These cannot be ran in a Windows DOS or Powershell prompt.

An `.exe` is windows-only executable format, which may in-turn execute a `.bat` script or other compiled code. Also cannot be directly used in a Unix prompt.

---

Each can easily launch a series of commands, or a single command that requires complex environment variables or arguments. You can open a .bat file or the .sh file in a text editor like notepad and view the commands they're running.

Comment: But 2.Why don't use *exe instead *sh, *bat file to run ?
How the structure in *bat, *sh file ??

Comment: @ThanhPhong It doesn't use *.exe for the same reason it uses both bat and sh - Unix doesn't know what an exe file is and so both are used in an effort to be cross-platform (why they're not using an actual cross-platform language like Perl is beyond me).